# PHP annotations used in YII

Tags: php, yii

Going through the auto generated code of YII for a Model class, I understand that the table columns are injected into the Model class through Annotations (@property)

```
<?php

/**
 * This is the model class for table "tbl_project".
 *
 * The followings are the available columns in table 'tbl_project':
 * @property integer $id
 * @property string $name
 */
class Project extends CActiveRecord
{
```

Here property $id and $name become part of the Project class and can be accessed like such:

```
$proj = new Project();
$proj->id = 1;
```

I tried to look up annotations in PHP but found nothing as all links point to either [PHPDoc](http://www.phpdoc.org/) . I am more interested in the Dependency Injection part of it. Can someone explain the concept please and point to a list of available annotations.

Comment: Yii does not parse annotations like Symphony does, these comments are just PHPDoc for documentation and autocompletion.

Comment: Yes I figured that out now Dcoder, thanks. Coming from a Java background I am used to @WebService and the like!  Over here, what *does* inject the table fields into the Model class is what I am after

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yii does not use annotations.
It uses table schema extracted from database.
If you remove annotations all will work.

This would be interesting for you http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbTableSchema

And here are some instructions how to speed up your app. One of ways is to enable schema caching. http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/blog/1.1/en/final.deployment

Comment: It is difficult to understand how the table columns are magically part of the Model class!  Thanks Bogdan for the links, I will investigate further :)

Comment: @Afser2000 Nothing difficult. Yii executes `SHOW COLUMNS FROM tablename` query and reads the result. You will see it if you install profiler.

Comment: Are you referring to XDebug or [Logging](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.logging) here?

Comment: @Afser2000 Oh, I use this extension, and recomend you too http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/dbprofiler/  . It will help you to know and to control queries number executed per page.

Answer (score 0):

The Block comments in are only to use with PHPDoc or for your own sense.

Although my IDE (PhpStorm) uses the phpdoc block comments and its properties for code inspection and code hinting.

As said in the comments, Yii does not parse the block comments for dependency purposes.